# How to assign an initialized array to an array of arrays in TwinCAT

Tags: plc, twincat, codesys, st, iec61131-3

I'm trying to assign two initialized arrays `evenNumbers` and `oddNumbers` to an array of arrays `integers`:

```
PROGRAM ArrayInit
VAR
    evenNumbers : ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := [2, 4, 6];
    oddNumbers: ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := [1, 3, 5];
    
    integers : ARRAY[1..2] OF ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := [evenNumbers, oddNumbers];
END_VAR
```

This code gives me a compiler error

> Array initialisation expected

Of course I can directly initialize `integers` with the numbers that I want like so:

```
PROGRAM ArrayInit
VAR
    integers: ARRAY[1..2] OF ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := [
        [2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]
    ];
END_VAR
```

or like Sergey mentioned

```
PROGRAM ArrayInit
VAR
    integers: ARRAY[1..2, 1..3] OF INT := [
        2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5
    ];
END_VAR
```

However, if the original arrays are very big and/or I want to document what these different arrays are, a descriptive name would be nice. I.e. `integers : ARRAY[1..2] OF ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := [evenNumbers, oddNumbers];` nicely shows that the `integers` has two lists, one with even and one with odd numbers.

I've also tried to initialize `integers` as `integers: ARRAY[1..2] OF ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := [[evenNumbers], [oddNumbers]];`, but this gives me the compiler error:

> Cannot convert type 'ARRAY [1..3] OF INT' to type 'INT'

Now I wonder if it even possible? If so, does anyone know how I can do it?

Comment: For more general information on how to initialize arrays, see this excellent [overview](https://hopperpop.github.io/posts/Init-array-in-ST/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To assign multiple level array you do it in one line.

```
combinedSet : ARRAY[1..2, 1..2] OF INT := [1,2,3,4];
```

will result in array

```
[
  1 => [
     1 => 1, 
     2 => 2
  ],
  2 => [
     1 => 2, 
     2 => 4
  ]
]
```

SO first it assign all element of first element `[1, 1]`, `[1, 2]`, `[1, 3]` ... and then nest one `[2, 1]`, `[2, 2]`, `[2, 3]` ...

**Additional information**

Most simple way to merge 2 arrays into one multi dimensional is:

```
PROGRAM PLC_PRG
    VAR
        arr1 : ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := [1,3,5];
        arr2 : ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := [2,4,6];
        combinedSet : ARRAY[1..2] OF ARRAY[1..3] OF INT;
    END_VAR
    
    combinedSet[1] := arr1;
    combinedSet[2] := arr2;
END_PROGRAM
```

The reason this does not work

```
integers : ARRAY[1..2] OF ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := [evenNumbers, oddNumbers];
```

Because `evenNumbers` and  `oddNumbers` are not initialized at the moment of use. If you would declare those in `VAR CONSTANT` it would probably work but then you would not be able to change content of those arrays in program.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Unfortunately this is not quite what I was looking for. I've updated the question to clarify it hopefully. I was wondering if it would be possible to reuse the initialized arrays `oddNumbers` and `evenNumbers`, such that it is clearer what is stored in the new array `integers`.

Comment: I added some additional answers. More complex way of merging arrays through memory allocations @Guiorgy had already posted.

Comment: Putting `evenNumbers` and `oddNumbers` into `VAR_GLOBAL CONSTANT` doesn't work unfortunately. Assigning them in the program itself (`combinedSet[1] := arr1;`) is also what I arrived at a certain point. I was hoping it was possible to do it directly in the declaration, but sadly that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

Your line `integers : ARRAY[1..2] OF ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := [evenNumbers, oddNumbers];` works fine when `evenNumbers` and `oddNumbers` are constants. You cannot use non-constant variables to initialize other variables.

In case you need `evenNumbers` and `oddNumbers` to be changed later, you could create two constants `evenNumbersConst` and `oddNumbersConst` and use them just for the initialization like so:

```
VAR
    evenNumbers : ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := evenNumbersConst;
    oddNumbers  : ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := oddNumbersConst;    
    integers : ARRAY[1..2] OF ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := [evenNumbersConst, oddNumbersConst];
END_VAR

VAR CONSTANT
    evenNumbersConst : ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := [2, 4, 6];
    oddNumbersConst  : ARRAY[1..3] OF INT := [1, 3, 5];
END_VAR
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I don't think you can join arrays while initializing a third</strike> (see the edit below). What you can do however is call a function at the start of the program once that joins those two arrays:

```hs
PROGRAM PLC_PRG
VAR
    arr1: ARRAY [0..2] OF INT := [1, 2, 3];
    arr2: ARRAY [0..2] OF INT := [4, 5, 6];
    arr3: ARRAY [0..5] OF INT;
    initialized: BOOL := FALSE;
END_VAR

IF (NOT initialized) THEN
    initialized := TRUE;
    JOIN_INT_ARRAYS(arr1 := arr1, arr2 := arr2, dest_arr := arr3);
END_IF
```

```hs
// Assume that:
//      - the destination ARRAY size can fit all source ARRAYs
//      - all ARRAYs store INTs
FUNCTION JOIN_INT_ARRAYS
VAR CONSTANT
    size_of_int: DWORD := SIZEOF(INT);
END_VAR
VAR_IN_OUT
    arr1: ARRAY [*] OF INT;
    arr2: ARRAY [*] OF INT;
    dest_arr: ARRAY [*] OF INT;
END_VAR
VAR
    arr1_len: DWORD := DINT_TO_DWORD(UPPER_BOUND(arr1, 1) - LOWER_BOUND(arr1, 1) + 1) * size_of_int;
END_VAR

MEMUtils.MemCpy(pbySrc := arr1, pbyDest := dest_arr, dwSize := arr1_len);
MEMUtils.MemCpy(pbySrc := arr2, pbyDest := dest_arr + arr1_len, dwSize := DINT_TO_DWORD(UPPER_BOUND(arr2, 1) - LOWER_BOUND(arr2, 1) + 1) * size_of_int);
```

Result:

[image: result.png]

*A few things to note:*

- I used the `MemCpy` function from the `MEMUtils` library. If you don't have it, or don't want to add it into your project, you can manually copy values from one array into another using a `FOR` loop.
- I have omitted range checking, which can be extremely dangerous. If you want extra protection, then add it yourself.
- avoid passing `arr_dest` as `arr1` or `arr2`. Trying to copy from an array into itself may lead into problems.

#### EDIT:

Actually, this seems to work:

```hs
integers: ARRAY [0..1] OF ARRAY [0..2] OF INT := [[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]];
evenNumbers: ARRAY [0..2] OF INT := integers[0];
oddNumbers: ARRAY [0..2] OF INT := integers[1];
```

result:

[image: result1.png]

But I don't know if this is your desired outcome. If you want a continuous array as the combined array, then you can try this:

```hs
// in Program
evenNumbers: ARRAY [0..2] OF INT := [2, 4, 6];
oddNumbers: ARRAY [0..2] OF INT := [1, 3, 5];
integers: ARRAY [0..5] OF INT := JOIN_INT_ARRAYS_3_3_6(arr1 := evenNumbers, arr2 := oddNumbers);
```

```hs
// (left)3 + (right)3 = (result)6
FUNCTION JOIN_INT_ARRAYS_3_3_6 : ARRAY [0..5] OF INT
VAR_IN_OUT
    arr1: ARRAY [0..2] OF INT;
    arr2: ARRAY [0..2] OF INT;
END_VAR
VAR
    i: USINT;
END_VAR

FOR i := 0 TO 2 DO
    JOIN_INT_ARRAYS_3_3_6[i] := arr1[i];
END_FOR
FOR i := 0 TO 2 DO
    JOIN_INT_ARRAYS_3_3_6[i + 3] := arr2[i];
END_FOR
```

and the result:

[image: result2.png]

However, with this method the function can't be general, so you will have to modify it's input and output array sizes every time the conditions change, and create many if you want to use this in several places, thus it's not elegant, and personally I'd avoid it, but if this works for you, then here it is.

Also, this seems to give me a `C0441:  Access to uninitialized VAR_IN_OUT variable` warning, so another reason to try to avoid it.

Comment: Nice way of merging arrays. Complex, advanced thus beautiful. Looks like code obfuscation for most PLC developers :)

Comment: Nice but a little complex indeed. Sadly assigning the values directly in the declaration doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: @Roald, check the edit ;)