# CODESYS: Can I assign and array to another array?

Tags: arrays, variable-assignment, assign, codesys

Can I perform the following operation in codesys?

```pascal
VAR

    abVariable_A:    ARRAY[0..15] OF BYTE := [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];

    abVariable_B:    ARRAY[1..16] OF BYTE := [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

END_VAR
```

`abVariable_B := abVariable_A;`

What would the result of `abVariable_B` be?
Can I expect it to be equal to

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]`

Or I will get

`[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]`

Please pay attention to the dimension of the arrays, although both have a dimension of 16, the indexes don't start at the same point. Does this affect the assignation of the arrays?

I expect `abVariable_B` to be equal to `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]`.

Comment: Here's a tip: If you want to initialize an array with the same value for every element, you can use the short notation: `[0,0,0,0,0]` is equivalent to `[5(0)]`. And if the initial value for the elements is `0` (zero), then you don't even need to explicitly initialize them, here's a quote from the documentation: `Elements to which no initialization value is assigned explicitly are initialized internally with the default value of the basic data type.`. The default value for integer data types is 0.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69853619/how-to-assign-an-initialized-array-to-an-array-of-arrays-in-twincat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a simple experiment by running:

```pascal
PROGRAM Test
VAR
    abVariable_A: ARRAY[0..15] OF BYTE := [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
    abVariable_B: ARRAY[1..16] OF BYTE := [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    
    pA_before: POINTER TO BYTE;
    pB_before: POINTER TO BYTE;
    pA_after: POINTER TO BYTE;
    pB_after: POINTER TO BYTE;
END_VAR

pA_before := ADR(abVariable_A);
pB_before := ADR(abVariable_B);

abVariable_B := abVariable_A;

pA_after := ADR(abVariable_A);
pB_after := ADR(abVariable_B);
END_PROGRAM
```

And observing the result:

[image: Results]

As we can see, the values in both arrays are the same, and array addresses didn't change (that means all values were copied, instead of just the array reference/pointer like in many other languages).

We can double check that the values were copied and that the arrays don't point to the same array by modifying one of the values in one array:

```pascal
abVariable_B := abVariable_A;
abVariable_B[3] := 255;
```

And observing the result:

[image: Results2]

This experiment shows that codesys treats array assignment as a memory copy for all values (at least in CODESYS 3.5.16, haven't tested this on older versions).

The initial index has absolutely no importance to the underlying memory layout of an array, it is just there for programmers convenience. However, the same can't be said about arrays of different length:

```pascal
abVariable_A: ARRAY[0..15] OF BYTE := [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
abVariable_B: ARRAY[1..18] OF BYTE := [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

Results in the `C0032:  Cannot convert type 'ARRAY [0..15] OF BYTE' to type 'ARRAY [1..18] OF BYTE'` error when we try to assign `abVariable_A` to `abVariable_B`.

Simmilar error is shown if `abVariable_A` is larger than `abVariable_B`.

If don't trust the built-in array assignment, or want to handle the above cases, where the arrays have different lengths, you could create a custom function, for example:

```pascal
FUNCTION ArrayCopy
VAR_INPUT
    destination: ANY;
    source: ANY;
END_VAR

MEMUtils.MemCpy(pbyDest := destination.pValue, pbySrc := source.pValue, MIN(destination.diSize, source.diSize));

END_FUNCTION
```

If we use it instead of the assignment:

```pascal
ArrayCopy(abVariable_B, abVariable_A);
abVariable_B[3] := 255;
```

The result is as expected:

[image: Results3]

Though, keep in mind, the function above requires the [MemoryUtils](https://help.codesys.com/webapp/ZidVRTnfzfI0LAYUwLYCsY_W-O4%2FMemCpy;product=MemoryUtils;version=3.5.17.0) library, and is just an example. Although it works with arrays of any type, it has drawbacks:

- It assumes passed arguments are both arrays, even though you can pass **anything**. If you decide to make use of it, I recommend checking the `TypeClass` values of the passed arguments.
- It assumes arrays are 1 dimensional, or if multidimensional, then the bounds of each dimension must match, otherwise the resulting order will be wrong.
- It assumes array elements are of the same type.
- It assumes array elements are value types, in other words, not pointers/references. If arrays of pointers are used, pointers will be copied, but underlying values the pointers point to will remain the same, so be careful.